# How to unclear the float?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my website: http://mlresearch.ml/

As you can see the **OUR ONGOING PROJECTS** section located at the right side of the page but somehow it's cannot move up and stay at the right side of the slider. If I add this style:

```
body.home .av_one_third {
    margin-top: -440px;
}
```

then it's displayed correctly, but how can I achieve the same result without using above style since it's quite fragile when I add or remove elements later on.

I suspect that the reason is coming from somewhere with the slider that clear the float and make the section cannot move up but not sure exactly where it is. So how can I achieve the expected result? (Javascript is welcomed too)

Comment: wrap slider and carousel in one div and set it to `float:left` then the sidebar will align properly

Comment: Providing minimal complete HTML+CSS instead of link to the site is welcomed too.

Comment: Looking at the site, I am pretty sure that the problem is that there is another element in between the two you are worried about.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not about clear your div. You have a simpler problem understanding how float works and what div you should place first in your file.

A quick solution could be to move `div.flex_column.av_one_third` to the first position inside your `div.entry-content` and then add `float:right`. Of course this might impact on your responsive layout.

I would recommend to study, understand and do CSS without frameworks so then you can improve your markup.

Another solution can be to redo your code and organise it in this way:

`div.main
    div.flex_column.av_two_third.first
    div.flex_column.av_two_third.first
div.sidebar
    div.flex_column.av_one_third`

Then you can decide what to float left, right and what to clear as well.

Answer (score 0):

It can't move up because there's an element in between the current location and top of your page..

try giving the element the following styles:

```
position: absolute;
```

this will take your element out of the flow of the page, thus allowing it to go to the top.

```
right: 5%;
```

this will cause the element to be 5% off the right side, you should just try a few numbers, I believe it's around 5% though,

if this doesn't work you could add:

```
clear: both;
float: right;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

After you use floating div always hav this empty div which will clear the floating property